# Defining scaladoc macros for reuse in companion object

Tags: scala, scaladoc

I am trying to understand how [scaladoc macros](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Tags+and+Annotations) [work](http://scabl.blogspot.co.at/2013/04/scaladoc-macros.html). E.g.

```
/** $DESCR
  *
  * @define DESCR
  * A `Consumer` simplifies resource management...
  *
  * @define KEY
  * the key type
  *
  * @define VALUE
  * the value type
  */
object Consumer {
  /** Creates a new consumer
    *
    * @tparam A       $KEY
    * @tparam B       $VALUE
    */
  def apply[A, B](): Consumer[A, B] = ???
}

/** $DESCR
  *
  * @tparam A $KEY
  * @tparam B $VALUE
  */
trait Consumer[-A, +B]
```

I was under the impression that this should produce a documentation which has both for trait and companion object the description `A Consumer simplifies resource management...`, and also shows the two type parameter descriptions in the `apply` method and the `trait`.

But the macros seem to be unavailable in the trait. While the object is correctly documented, the trait doc just shows the macro names `$DESCR`, `$KEY`, `$VALUE`.